# Emacs: set key that is local to java mode.

Tags: java, emacs

I am inspired by this [url](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/03/29/automatic-electric-indentation/).

It suggests setting a global key `(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)`.

However, I would like to set `RET` to `'newline-and-indent` ONLY in the Java mode. What code should I add to the `init.el` in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply it to the mode specific keymap. Something like the below should work.

```lisp
(defun on-java-loaded ()
  (define-key java-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'on-java-loaded)
```

Comment: That works, but the naming is misleading. `java-mode-hook` runs *every time* any buffer runs `java-mode`, whereas the library itself is only loaded once. `eval-after-load` is the way to run something once, after a library is loaded. The hook approach is absolutely fine, but I'd recommend calling the function something more appropriate (FWIW I use `my-MODE-hook` for custom `MODE-hook` functions).